# Getting error "bash: appletviewer: command not found".

Tags: java, linux, bash, appletviewer

I'm trying to learn Java and I'm having problems with the appletviewer command. I am using openSUSE 11 and am able to compile and run normal java programs but when I issue the appletviewer command I'm getting the following error "bash: appletviewer: command not found".

I have set the PATH variable in the .bashrc file. so the problem is not that of the path. This can also be verified from the fact that javac and java commands are working normally. I have googled and tried many said resolution but none is working. I have even tried moving the files to the bin folder and running the command from there.

So what may the cause of this? Isn't appletviewer designed to work in linux? And FYI I have replaced the OpenSDK and IcedTea versions with the jdk1.6.0_14 version from the sun site. Please help.

Thanks
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a test, do the following:

```
$which java
$which appletviewer
```

Check to see if the paths are different. If the second command gives no output, appletviewer may not even be installed (or can't be located by your system).

Comment: yes, i think it is the issue. which appletviewer is saying 
which: no appletviewer in (/home/chryste/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin/X11:/usr/X11R6/bin:/usr/games:/usr/lib/jvm/jre/bin:/usr/lib/mit/bin:/usr/lib/mit/sbin:/opt/kde3/bin)
So I copied appletviewer to /usr/bin directory
now it is giving the error
appletviewer: error while loading shared libraries: libjli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

So I think this is not the way to resolve it. Sorry if I am too dumb. I'm just a beginner. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Try reinstalling using Robert's suggestion. Since you've relocated the bin, it can't find the libraries it needs to work. A proper install should avoid all of these pathing issues altogether.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install java-1_6_0-sun-devel-1.6.0.u14-0.2.1

```
$ sudo zypper install java-1_6_0-sun-devel
```

You will find it in the `openSUSE-11.1-Non-Oss` repository.